# Where are the information about each workspace stored?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that some settings such as imported folders are store on the workspace file such as `my-worskapce.code-workspace` and some others such as python interpreter are stored in the root folder(s?) such as `.vscode/settings.json` but these do not include information about opened editors or which extensions are disabled for each workspace etc. Where can I find those information?

I need that information because I started storing all my `*.code-workspace` files in `~/` and now it's getting cluttered and I want to move them to a different folder, when I do, and reopen my workspace, I see that all open editors are gone! This hurts my productivity as I will have to reopen them and recall which files were being worked on. And another issue is that previously added folders are gone too! I have to re-add them which is merely a redo of work that already has been done, since imported folders are imported as relative paths. If I move the `*.code-workspace` file to it's original location with the same name however, everything is back to normal, so this tells me VSCode is storing information about each workspace somewhere and it's bound to each `*.code-workspace` absolute path. I have checked `~/.config/Code/User` but couldn't find anything. I've googled a lot using different keywords but seems it's nowhere documented or asked about. I usually make backups of my workspace files and I'd like to make back up of these information as well.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can find them in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
```

For Mac

```
${HOME}/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/
```

Answer (score 1):

**VS Code 1.75** introduced a new Profiles feature, summarised [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_profiles).

Profiles store information such as user settings, installed extensions and the current layout of panels etc.

You can export/import profiles to/from a Github gist or a local file. Different profiles are associated with each workspace.

Profiles won't resolve all your immediate issues, but may give you more flexibility in the future.